# How to insert dynamically *multiple* input fields in a row to mysql using java

Tags: java, mysql, arrays, servlets, jdbc

I have an exact/similar problem with: [How to insert dynamically created field values to MySQL db using Java/JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66652003/20958522) on How to insert dynamically created field values to MySQL db using Java/JDBC?

There's one answer that solved the problem above, but instead of one dynamically created field values (multiple phone numbers) I have to insert multiple dynamic field values in a row for example (size, price, stocks)
[Image of multiple input fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abFFi.jpg)

Solution that I found: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66691466/20958522

Here is the code following the guide from the solution:

Aside from inserting multiple fields value from quantity, I also need to insert multiple weight, rate, and price into MySQL. What can I do to modify the code to be able to insert multiple input fields in a row to the database?

**/Insert servlet**

```java
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        String shoe_name= request.getParameter("shoe_name");            
        String[] quantity = request.getParameterValues("quantity");
        
        List<String> qty = new ArrayList<>();
        if (quantity != null) {
          qty = Arrays.asList(quantity);
        }
        
        String weight = request.getParameter("weight");
        String rate= request.getParameter("rate");
        String price = request.getParameter("price");
        String status = "2";
                    
        User newUser = new User(shoe_name, qty, weight, rate, price, status);
        
        userDAO.insertUser(newUser);
        response.sendRedirect("List");
        System.out.println("Added Successfully");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**userDAO.java code**
(insert to database)

```
//INSERT ITEMS
public void insertUser(User user) throws SQLException, FileNotFoundException {
    List<String> quantity = user.getQuantity();
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    
    if (quantity != null && !quantity.isEmpty()) {

    try (Connection connection = getConnection()){ 
     preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_USERS_SQL); 
    
     for (String qty : quantity) {

        preparedStatement.setString(1, user.getShoe_name());
  //    preparedStatement.setString(2, user.getQuantity());
        
        preparedStatement.setString(2, qty);
        preparedStatement.setString(3, user.getWeight());
        preparedStatement.setString(4, user.getRate());
        preparedStatement.setString(5, user.getPrice());
        preparedStatement.setString(6, user.getStatus());
        preparedStatement.addBatch(); //remove

     }   
     
     System.out.println(preparedStatement);
//     preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
     preparedStatement.executeBatch();
     
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        printSQLException(e);
    }catch(Exception ex) { 
        ex.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
   }
}
```

**user.java**

```
public class User {
    
    private int product_id;
    private String shoe_name;
    private List<String> quantity = new ArrayList<>();
    private String qty;
    private String weight;
    private String rate;
    private String price;
    private String status = "2";

    public User(String shoe_name, List<String> quantity, String weight, String rate, String price, String status) {
        super();
        this.shoe_name = shoe_name;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.rate = rate;
        this.price = price;
        this.status = status;

    }

    public void addQty(String quantity) {
        if (this.quantity == null) {
          this.quantity = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        this.quantity.add(quantity);
      }


/*
* SETTERS AND GETTERS */
```

Comment: Create a new `User` for each row and not one user with a list property

Comment: Please ask about only one problem per question.

Comment: So if you want to persist _shoes_, why on earth your class is called `User`?